# add cell in Excel for each cell in other column that contains value

Tags: excel

I need to insert another cell for each cell that contains some value.

this will explain it :
[image]

Now, what I need is to create cell in "IN PROGRESS" column with "Compeny" value for each cell in "Name" column that contains the value "jhon".

can someone help me with it ?

Answer (score 0):

got it!!

I cannot upload here excel file, so you can download it from this link:
http://www.excelforum.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=396259&d=1432192664